# Creating a function for converting decomposed graph to dataframe

Tags: r, function

I have this commands that turn the decomposed graph into a table, which works well.

```
dat <- with(decomposed,data.frame(Observed = x, Trend = trend, Seasonal = seasonal, Random = random)) 
dat$Date <- seq(as.Date("yyyy-mm-dd"), as.Date("yyyy-mm-dd"), by = "week")
colnames(dat)[1] <- "Observed"
colnames(dat)[4] <- "Random"
```

Since i have to do this a lot of times i thought of writing a function. I want in the function to be able to select both the dates and the object. This is what i have tried so far without any success.

```
decomposed_table <- function(x, start.date, end.date){
xx <- with(x,data.frame(Observed = x, Trend = trend, Seasonal = seasonal, Random = random))
xx$Date <- seq(as.Date("yyyy-mm-dd"), as.Date("yyyy-mm-dd"), by = "week")
colnames(xx)[1] <- "Observed"
colnames(xx)[4] <- "Random"
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated since i am quite stuck.

Comment: Hello ! Can you please provide some data to work with? If they are confidential, you can use the base R datasets (such as `mtcars`). Have tried to use your function with `apply()` or `lapply()`?

Comment: Hello Paul! Thanks for your message. I am including some sample data below.                
library(TTR)

t <- ts(co2, frequency=12)
decomposed <- decompose(t)
plot(decomposed)

xx <- with(decomposed,data.frame(Observed = x, Trend = trend, Seasonal = seasonal, Random = random)) 
xx$Date <- seq(as.Date("yyyy-mm-dd"), as.Date("yyyy-mm-dd"), by = "week")
colnames(xx)[1] <- "Observed"
colnames(xx)[4] <- "Random"

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to find something to propose :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done, I have been facing some problems to make your code work with the sample you game me in you comment. So feel free to make some comments so I can improve it.

```
# data from your comment
    t <- ts(co2, frequency=12) 
    decomposed <- decompose(t)

# here starts the modifications you want to make to many decomposed-like objects
    dat <- with(decomposed,data.frame(Observed = x, Trend = trend, Seasonal = seasonal, Random = random)) 
    dat$Date <- seq(as.Date("yyyy-mm-dd"), as.Date("yyyy-mm-dd"), by = "week") # this lines creates an error
    colnames(dat)[1] <- "Observed" # I do not understand this line as you have already renamed you column inside the "with()" function
    colnames(dat)[4] <- "Random" # idem
```

So, I understand you have many decomposed-like lists and you want to apply some transformations to them.
What I would do it to put all these decomposed-like objects in a single list and use `lapply()` to use the funtction you defined on each of them. For the purpose of the example I have simplified your function.

```
t <- ts(co2, frequency=12) 
decomposed <- decompose(t)
# create your function
function_ex = function(x) {
  xx =  with(decomposed,
             data.frame(Observed = x, 
                        Trend = trend, 
                        Seasonal = seasonal, 
                        Random = random))
}

# create a list of decomposed-like objects 
example = list(a = decomposed, b = decomposed)

# and apply the function on them
output = lapply(example, FUN = function_ex) # output is also a list but you can do whatever you want with it such as extract all tables in your environment, etc.
```